# why imeOptions in my Edit text stops work

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, window, imeoptions

`ImeOptions` in my `EditText` stops work before add `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false);`
when expanding the frame, the `ImeOptions` in `EditText` stops working and I can't see what I'm typing

Here are the examples:

- [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZB3c.png)
- [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFieO.png)

I set the following attributes

```xml
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"/>
```

I found the same problem but it was answered on kotlin so I created this one

I will be very grateful for every reply

Comment: You should add a link of the problem answered in kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not what you are looking for, everything is fine with imeoptioins.

This kind of error can occur if there are recyclerView in your layout (that is, if you remove recyclerView , everything will work), but this is another issue.

Comment: I went to look for it, thanks